# New to Python, please what is wrong with my statement?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

## Python says that If self.age > 50 that statement appears to have no effect

def favoriteColor(self):
        ##self.color = favorite_color
        #Determine color depending on age

```
    If self.age > 50  
    self.color = "blue"

    elif self.age > 10 and self.age < 20
    self.color = "green"

    elif self.age < 10
    self.color = "red"
    return
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code, `If` instead of `if`, no colons, indentation. You need to go back to a tutorial and try again.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Comment: also take care to use == instead of =. If or if matters, indentation matters, also use : after if statement.

Comment: and try to paste a complete example

Answer (score 1):

I think you have switched from another language or learning from a wrong source.

```
if self.age > 50 : 
    self.color = "blue"

elif self.age > 10 and self.age < 20 :
    self.color = "green"

elif self.age < 10 :
    self.color = "red"
return "whatever you want"
```

Please use proper indentation, colons, spellings, and **everything** correctly!